# Is `Monad` constraint necessary in `<$!>`

Tags: haskell

As claimed in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#g:8) `<$!>` is the strict version of `<$>`, but surprisingly

```
<$!> :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b 
f <$!> m = do
  x <- m
  let z = f x
  z `seq` return z
```

instead of the more natural (*in my opinion; because it keeps the weaker constraint and mimics `$!`*)

```
<$!> :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
f <$!> x = x `seq` (f <$> x)
```

I guess that appliying `seq` after the binding is different than the "natural" approach, but I don't know how different it is. My question is: Is there any reason which makes the "natural" approach useless, and that's why the implementation is constraint to `Monad`?

Comment: You're right that it's not really analogous to `$!`, but it's actually a whole lot more useful this way. Perhaps/arguably, the name should rather be `<!$>` instead of `<$!>`. The point being, whereas `$!` is about forcing the _arguments_ to the function, `<$!>` is about forcing its _results_. (Which wouldn't make sense for `$!`, because there the result is forced by just... well, forcing the result.) Your `f<$!>x` can be easily achieved as `fmap f $! x`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout arguably this function should be introduce as a strict version of `liftM` which makes more sense... something like `liftM'` with an infix version `<!$>` as you propose

Comment: But `liftM` is kind of deprecated as a historical quirk, an artifact of `Monad` formerly lacking `Functor` as a superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that appliying seq after the binding is different than the "natural" approach, but I don't know how different it is

Since haskell is functional, `seq` must work through data dependencies; it sets up a relationship: "when `seq x y` is evaluated to WHNF, `a` will have been as well".

The idea here is to pin the evaluation of `a` to the outer `m a` which we know must be evaluated for each `>>=` or `<*>` to proceed.

In your version:

```
Prelude> f <$!> x = x `seq` (f <$> x)
Prelude> let thunk = error "explode"
Prelude> case (+) <$!> Just thunk <*> Just thunk of ; Just _ -> "we can easily build up thunks"
"we can easily build up thunks"
```

I do wonder if there's a better solution possible though

Comment: The actuall approach would fail since it evaluates `thunk` isn't it? What I wonder is: `<$!>` is constraint to `Monad` because in practise is _more_ usefull or because is the _only_ way to be usefull.

Answer (score 4):

GHC's [commit message](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/0148a1c416e42a7d7c9ff3624a0640963bfe0012) includes the following two links which sheds more light on this function:

- https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-November/021728.html
- https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-April/022864.html

This was the reason which is mentioned by Johan Tibell for it (quoting from the linked mailing list):

> It works on Monads instead of Functors as required by us inspecting
>   the argument.
>
> This version is highly convenient if you want to work with
>   functors/applicatives in e.g. parser and avoid spurious thunks at the
>   same time. I realized that it was needed while fixing large space
>   usage (but not space-leak) issues in cassava.